# Read/write certificates on a SIM card - iOS

Tags: iphone, certificate, sim-card

I'm doing some research on the way to use a certificate from a SIM Card (in order to keep the service provided, if the user wants to change his phone).

In Android, it seems OK, but I can't find anything in the iOS platform: is it possible to read X.509 certificates from the SIM card through an iPhone device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.**

Your best bet is to use either the [Keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html) or [iCloud](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/index.php) to persist data between devices.

Comment: Thanks for the accuracy :)
However, the aim of this service is to foresee the buy of a new device (not only Apple :S), so iCloud does not seem a good idea.
It's even not possible to read some infos written in the SIM card?

Bye !