# HTTP Server on SIM Card & Certification

Tags: security, http, certificate, x509certificate, sim-card

I was wondering how to read certificates put in a SIM Card, (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705603/read-write-certificates-on-a-sim-card-ios), but the fact was it depended every time on the phone considered, what was a bit unconvenient.
Then I bumped into this report, saying that you could implement [secure HTTP Servers on SIM cards.](http://www.iaeng.org/publication/WCE2010/WCE2010_pp253-259.pdf)

My question : does someone know how to configure/use this technology? For instance, check certificates *via* http ? (Any Documentation would be welcomed ! )

Thanks,

Comment: You can do any computation with a smart card, as it is a general purpose CPU - even though they are pretty limited on resources. But I don't get where you are going with this question, what are you trying to achieve? Normally you cannot just program a smart card to return the certificates stored on it, if that's what you are trying to do.

Comment: I actually intend to use private keys (for instance) to sign certificates (PDF, anything). The problem is, the private key must not go outside the card (question of security). So I look at the certification with a SIM card.

Comment: Digital certificates and certification are quite different concepts, moutonjr, currently your question and remark do not show you've made a study of the subject at hand. I would advice you get more acquainted with smart card technology and PKI. Not to bug you, but as it stands your question cannot be answered.

Comment: OK I've read a bunch of documentation about it, and it appears that I misunderstood the use of certificates. I'll try to learn more about signature with SIM card, except if you have ideas, how to do so, owlstead.

Comment: I wish I had more for you moutonjr, but I can only say that implementing HTTP server on the SIM card is unlikely to get you access to certificates stored in the SIM card.